# SQL Server: how to find maximum length continuous range?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table containing one integer column (signed) `NUM`.

In each row, this table contains a random number. Each number is found in the table an arbitrary number of times.

I need to find the maximum length of a continuous (without missing numbers) range,
present in the table, missed is considered.

Number in the range of min(NUM) max(NUM) (where min and max functions of SQL)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Provide some sample data and sample output you would want.

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--make test data
select 1 as val into #test;

insert #test (val) 
values (1),(1),(2),(3),(4),(4),(5),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13);

select * from #test;

--With command to find start and end of 'ranges'
--then join start of range to its corresponding end, with length
--then list the longest ranges (with ties)
;WITH LB AS (SELECT t1.val from #test t1 LEFT JOIN #test t2 on t1.val - 1 = t2.val WHERE t2.val is null),
      UB AS (SELECT t1.val from #test t1 LEFT JOIN #test t2 on t1.val + 1 = t2.val WHERE t2.val is null),
      Ranges AS (SELECT DISTINCT LB.val s, Q.val e,q.val-lb.val + 1 cnt FROM LB 
                        CROSS APPLY  
                            (SELECT TOP 1 val FROM UB WHERE UB.val >= LB.val  ORDER BY UB.val) Q)
      SELECT TOP 1 with ties * FROM Ranges order by cnt DESC


drop table #test;
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a typical gaps-and-islands problem:

```
SELECT TOP 1 MIN(num) num_from, MAX(num) num_upto, COUNT(DISTINCT num) num_count
FROM (
    SELECT num, SUM(num_changed) OVER (ORDER BY num) num_groupno
    FROM (
        SELECT num, CASE WHEN LAG(num) OVER (ORDER BY num) BETWEEN num - 1 AND num THEN 0 ELSE 1 END num_changed
        FROM (VALUES
            (1),
            (2),
            (3),

            (5),
            (6),
            (7),
            (7),
            (8),

            (10)
        ) v(num)
    ) cte1
) cte2
GROUP BY num_groupno
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT num) DESC
```

Result:

```
num_from    num_upto    num_count
5           8           4
```